# Gateway: receiving data with LoRa and sending with GPRS to a server

Tags: iot, gateway, gprs, lora

I'm building a gateway for an IoT project. I need to receive sensor data (from an end device) with LoRa (RFM95) and send it to a Cayenne server with GPRS (SIM800C).

The PCB is almost ready but I'm stuck at the coding part. How to configure it to work with two different protocols?